# Key capture directive not working as intended in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to capture keypress events in my angular app.
The intended functionality is that upon pressing g1 (i.e simulataneously pressing g and 1) the app should transition to state1. Upon pressing g2 the app should transition to state2 and so on.

However the app does not seem to be capturing two keypresses simulataneously. What am I missing here ?
Also is this the best way to achieve this or are there better solutions available.

You can see the plnkr here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/sK0NYNDRtH4lFfteNd5O

Comment: How can e.keyCode be equal to an integer, but then a totally different integer at the same time? Read your code again :) (console.log e.keyCode for clues)

Comment: It is a integer Chris..

Comment: Sorry James, I wasn't clear. See this example:
if (e.keyCode === 71 && e.keyCode == 50)

It can't be equal to 71, but also equal to 50. The value is an integer, it's either 71 or 50 - not both.

Comment: true .. i see your point.. any clue how to handle this kind of multiple events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the e.codeValue to a service/controller which then stores the keys pressed in an array.

On key press up, tell the service/controller to remove it from the "key pressed" array.

In the service/controller, you can then use your logic to see if g and 1 are in the array - if they are, do the state transition. That could work, although not 100% if it's the best way. Give it a try and let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: This approach an an alternate variable based approach.. both worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single-threaded, so there is no way for the following `if` statement to ever run the `true` block:

```
if (x == 3 && x == 4) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Aside from that, the real problem you're facing is that (to my knowledge) the browser does not directly expose rollover scan codes to Javascript.  By the time the browser gets the keystrokes they're already de-rollovered (if that's a word).

BTW, style note:  It's better to post your code here on Stack Overflow to save it for posterity for other readers to learn from.  Adding a plunkr is a nice courtesy, but it's secondary.